# Writing a scala function which can take Int or Double values

Tags: scala

I have written a function to accept the below type of values:
(1, Array(1.0,2.0,3.0)) 
That is a Tuple with Int being first value and next being an Array of Doubles.

I would also like it to accept an Array of Integers as well. The function I have written is as below:

```
def getCountsAndAverages[T](Parameter: Tuple2[Int, Array[T]])(implicit n:Numeric[T]) = {
(Parameter._1, (Parameter._2.size,   Parameter._2.map(n.toDouble).sum/Parameter._2.size)) 
}
```

The tuple's first parameter is a number and then its an Array of number of times it appears in the file.

It is working fine for sample cases, however I am reading a text file which has the data in the same format as needed for this function to work. I am calling this function using 'map' operation as:

```
parsedfile.map(getCountsAndAverages)
```

I am getting the below errors:

```
◾could not find implicit value for parameter n: Numeric[T]
◾not enough arguments for method getCountsAndAverages: (implicit n: Numeric[T])(Int, (Int, Double)). Unspecified value parameter n.
```

I would be grateful for any help or suggestions

Comment: What is the type of `parsedFile`?

Comment: The parsedFile has tuples in the format: (Int, Iterable[Double]). For example:
(1, Iterable(1.0,1.0,.1.0))
(2, Iterable(1.0,1.0,.1.0,1.0,1.0)) and so on...

Answer (score 3):

You can use any one of the following syntax

```
def foo[T](x: T)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = n.toDouble(x)
```

or

```
def foo[T : Numeric](x: T) = implicitly[Numeric[T]].toDouble(x)
```

In your case

```
def getCountsAndAverages[T: Numeric](Parameter: Tuple2[Int, Array[T]]) = {
 (Parameter._1, (Parameter._2.size, Parameter._2.map(implicitly[Numeric[T]].toDouble(_)).sum / Parameter._2.size))
}
```

Comment: one more, that seems the simplest to me, is to just use view bounds...    `def foo[T <% Double](x: T) = x.toDouble`

Comment: View bounds are going to be deprecated - https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629

Comment: I would not like to use view bounds for exactly the same reason.

Comment: Pamu: I used the logic you have provided, however, I am still getting the error as: 
◾could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Numeric[T]
◾not enough arguments for method getCountsAndAverages: (implicit evidence$1: Numeric[T])(Int, (Int, Double)). Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.

Comment: @pamu, the solution you provided works perfectly after I call the method as : map(getCountsAndAverages(_)) rather than map(getCountsAndAverages). At this point I am not sure what is the difference between the two calls though.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Iterable` isn't `Array`, so your function can't work on it. You can define `def getCountsAndAverages[T](Parameter: Tuple2[Int, Iterable[T]])(implicit n:Numeric[T])` instead. But in this case `Parameter._2.map(n.toDouble).sum/Parameter._2.size` may be inefficient, depending on the actual runtime type of `Parameter._2`. You may want to write it as a fold instead.
2. Change the `map` call to `parsedfile.map(getCountsAndAverages(_))`.

When you write `parsedfile.map(getCountsAndAverages)`, it is converted to an anonymous function using [eta-expansion](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion). But is seems to happen before type parameter inference, so you end up with `(x: T) => getCountsAndAverages(x)` for arbitrary `T`, which doesn't compile. `parsedfile.map(getCountsAndAverages[Double])` works as well. This is a known unresolved issue: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7641.

Comment: Thanks for helping, and it works like a charm. Many many thanks. However, before we close out here, would you mind explaining the solution in a couple of lines? I mean why does "getCountsAndAverages(_)"  work instead of simply "getCountsAndAverages"

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: doesn't the Scala compiler have enough information to do this by itself? if so, would this be a scala feature request, or a scala bug? if not, why not?