# Scala, different behaviour when calling `map(f)` vs `map(v => f(v))`

Tags: scala

I get a different behaviour when calling `map(f)` vs `map(v => f(v))`. Why?

```
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "pprint" % "0.4.1"

case class Entry(id: Int, text: String)
val entry = Entry(1, "hello")

def toPrettyString[T](o: T)(implicit pp: pprint.PPrint[T]) =
  pprint.tokenize(o)(pp).mkString

println(toPrettyString(entry))                            // I get Entry(1, "hello"), as expected

List(entry).map(toPrettyString).foreach(println)          // I get Entry(1,hello), not what I want
List(entry).map(e => toPrettyString(e)).foreach(println)  // I get Entry(1, "hello"), as expected
```

Comment: Oh, wow, that's a nice one. I'd count that as a bug if pprint was my library—it's probably worth opening an issue.

Comment: What is the signature / declaration of `pprint`?

Comment: https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle-pprint/blob/9e27753566ff4c1464e48024fb1a299a3ca106e5/pprint/shared/src/main/scala/pprint/package.scala

Comment: @Travis, why would it be a `pprint` bug? I thought that `list.map(f)` and `list.map(v => f(v))` are equivalent for whatever `list`, `f` and `v`. Isn't that the case?

Comment: I just happened to answer the same question in a different context today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023053/writing-a-scala-function-which-can-take-int-or-double-values/40029704#40029704.

Comment: @DavidPortabella I'm pretty sure this is an interaction of type inference, eta expansion, and the macro. I don't think it'd be possible to see the same thing with a non-macro default instance.

Comment: @DavidPortabella Oh, no, I'm wrong—this is what you see any time you have an unconstrained generic instance. Weird.

Comment: @Travis, Alexey pointed to the scala issue: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7641

Comment: @DavidPortabella Yeah, I've internalized SI-7641—what's surprising to me here is that the eta-expansion works (and is inconsistent with the anonymous function version) if you have the generic instance.

Comment: @Alexey, please write an answer (with your comment) so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eta-expansion (which turns the method `toPrettyString` used as a value into an anonymous function) happens before type parameter inference, you can think of it as equivalent to

```
def toPrettyString1[T]: T => String = 
  (x: T) => toPrettyString(x)

List(entry).map(toPrettyString1)
```

in `toPrettyString1`, the default implicit instance of `PPrint`, which just calls `toString`, has to be chosen.

In `List(entry).map(e => toPrettyString(e))`, type of `e` is inferred to be `Entry` and so the macro generates the correct implicit.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7641